# Snowflake using CTE to create table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowflake allow you to create a series of CTEs then join them together at the end to create a table?

For example:

```
with CTE1 as ( SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
,CTE2 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2)
,CTE3 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE3)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME_HERE AS 
SELECT * FROM CTE1 AS 1
LEFT JOIN CTE2 AS 2 ON 1.KEY = 2.KEY
LEFT JOIN CTE3 AS 3 ON 1.KEY = 3.KEY
```

I'm getting a `unexpected 'CREATE'.` error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME_HERE AS 
WITH CTE1 as ( SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
    ,CTE2 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2)
    ,CTE3 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE3)
SELECT *     -- here should be explicit column list to avoid name duplication error
FROM CTE1 AS 1
LEFT JOIN CTE2 AS 2 ON 1.KEY = 2.KEY
LEFT JOIN CTE3 AS 3 ON 1.KEY = 3.KEY;
```

Comment: OHHH - you have to put the create table before you create the CTEs. When I try that i'm getting ```object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.``` Does Snowflake require you make the table first?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out, the table name should not include the database,schema, etc...

Answer (score 5):

It's an interesting one, because that CTAS (CREATE TABLE AS) form is

```
CREATE TABLE <name> AS <select>
```

and SELECT form is can have a CTE and a CTE form is

```
WITH <name> AS <select>
```

CTE can also be in sub-select given "it's just a select", thus

```
SELECT <columns> 
FROM (
    WITH cte_1 AS (
         SELECT <columns>
         FROM table
    )
    SELECT <columns>
    FROM cte_1
)
```

which shows why the form that Lukasz shows is correct because if we add more parens

```
CREATE TABLE name AS (
    WITH cte_1 AS (
        SELECT <columns>
        FROM table
    )
    SELECT <columns>
    FROM cte_1
)
```

Comment: Makes sense, I just come from a Microsoft SQL server background and you can place the CTEs above the table create function.

Comment: nod, that makes much sense as how you got here. T-SQL has much more flexible CTE (e.g. recursion) support than Snowflake.